# Resources to learn MVx architecture for android

Tags: android, model-view-controller, mvp

This is probably my third try to master what MVx is all about. So far I have tried youtube videos, loads of medium articles and then I finally settled on a Udemy course by Vasiliy Zukanov{https://www.udemy.com/android-architecture/}. Now I had been following Google's blueprint (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) for android architecture till now however this author basically calls Google's implementation crap.

He says *The core issue here is that the view is the one who handles user interactions and decides what should be done. In other words, in addition to UI layer logic the view also contains large part of application layer logic. Another thing about MVP is that views should be reusable. For example, you should be able to write composite views that contain other views. In this implementation that would be impossible because each view is tightly coupled to the presenter. There is simply now way to reuse the view without its presenter, therefore, no composition. So contrary to MVP paradigm the presenter in this implementation takes commands from the view. In addition, the view is not easily replaceable and it is not reusable without the presenter. The only reasonable conclusion from all that is that this blueprint is not MVP. Even though the code has views and presenters, these components are tightly coupled to each other and there is no proper boundary between the UI layer and the application layer*

If someone has done the Udemy course ,you'll know the authors own implementation is quite pain in the ass to follow through.(https://github.com/techyourchance/android-architecture-course) .

I am really confused about all this, even more than I started. Why can't everyone follow the same approach like they do in Swift for ios. Do you guys use any architecture in your applications?If yes, please share what resources and approach do you use.

Comment: Hi Shivam, Good luck with your learning journey. Unfortunately your question is **NOT** on topic, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) the type of questions that are allowed for stackoverflow community. I suggest you to try other communities which allow discussions of an opinion-based answers

Answer (score 0):

Learning GUI architectures is difficult. I've been using and researching them for a long time and understand how frustrating it can be.

I'll suggest reading [this article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) by Martin Folwer and [this one](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2007/08/25/interactive-application-architecture/). I'll give some principles and practices I use when learning and reseaching. And of you need to write ***a lot*** of code so you can understand the things you learn better.

Here are couple of important thing from my experience.

- *Some patterns/architectures were developed and/or refined by specific technologies*.

Some of these technlogies are no longer in use, so it's natural that these patterns/architectures evolve or new ones are created using older ones as a base (for ideas of principles) to accomodate this.

MVP and MVC are an example of this. The original [MVC](https://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/1979/mvc-1/1979-05-MVC.pdf) was concieved in the seventies, so in that time the conroller received user input to handle the specific problems that they had then. After that, frameworks and libraries that we use today implement these pattern have changed. Also the complexity of the application changed. MVC had some problems that remainded unclear how to solve them. This is explained in the arcitles above in more details. The MVP came after that, using MVC as a base. [Here's](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf) the origical paper on MVP. The presenter was given the responsibility of having application logic to handle more complex cases.

Yes, we do it. We all use frameworks and libraries to implement stuff and it's not a bad thing. And yes, we do develop patterns to help us with these technologies, for better or worse. After that, we tend to generalize these patterns so we can use them in another technology, but sometimes it's difficult.

An example of this is the [Presentation Model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html). It relies on having a good *DataBinding* mechanism. It's a great pattern and you can develop applications with it very fast, it's just that if you lack ***DataBinding*** it will *be a pant and will slow you down a lot* so it may be not worth using it for *technological* reasons rather then *architectural*. That's the life of a developer :)

So the next thing is:

- *Don't learn about patterns/architectures from technologies that are adopting them.*

Learn from were these patterns came from. Learn about their history. Take into account the complexity of the applications and the technology available at the time they were created.

Understand what is the idea behind them and then go to specific technologies. Patterns/Architectures are a base for creating things. Change and adopt them if you need to. Don't hesitate to experiment

- *Patterns don't solve all the problems*

You need to change, modify and mix patterns so you can solve your problems. You need to understand them well so you can find their limits. When you hit a limit do what every good developer should do: *Make your own solution to problems*. This is what people have done. This is why we have MVP, because people had problems with MVC and they *changed it* to someting else.

If we could have a pattern that solves all our problems we wouldn't have more. Yet we have a lot of them.

- *Understand all parts of a pattern*

People do concentrate on some parts of a pattern more than others. This is the case with the ***Model*** in all MV* patterns. People tend to ignore how important it is. They design [Anemic Models](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) moving logic to Services and Presenters.

***AnemicModel*** is not the concept of ***Model*** that people concieved, that has data and behavior and models things like a ***Vector*** in mathematical or the operation of a ***BankTransfer***. It's just data that other components modify and abuse.

Then people have trouble understanding how to the share stuff between their Presenters. If they do understand what is an [ApplicationModel](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) and a [DomainModel](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) they won't have these problems.

Yet all people do think about the Presenter as the thing that runs the show, so they put so much logic that doesn't belond in it.

Code get's ugly, messy and hard to understand and modify.

- *Understand the specific technology you are using. Some tchnologies are developed for specific needs: mobile, desktop, web etc.*

Deloping framework and libraries is ***hard***. Sometimes they do tend to make using patterns more difficult. Understand the technology and the motivation behind it, the logic behind it and the context that it was developed in.

Sometimes technologies that are used for mobile applications are different then technologies used for desktop and web. It's natural.

It's tue that sometimes new technologies can mix things up and having a *clean* implementation of a pattern can be difficult, but if you get the idea of the patterns you can use the specific technology to fit your needs.

And a very importand one:

- *Don't try to fit **problems** to **solution**, fit **solutions** to **problems***

Technologies, patterns, architectures etc are *solutions* to *problems*. Understand the problems that they solve. Understand your problems and use these solutions to solve your problems by modifying and extending them.

Often people do take somethings like MVP and try to use it to solve all their problems. It doesn't work that way. Sometimes you have a problem that doesn't fit MVP well. In this case you either modify the pattern or use a different one.

Here's list of resources that you can use.

- https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html
- https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html
- https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html
- https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html
- http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2007/08/25/interactive-application-architecture/
- http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/26/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents/
- [https://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)
- https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6827095